# running a delay inside a loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

first off I'm just an airline pilot coding on my dead hours sitting in hotel rooms so pardon my ignorance.
I'm writing this Blackjack Game using Obj. C and Cocos2D. for iOS
My problem is as follows:
When I hit stand I want my code to draw cards for the dealer until it reaches 17. I managed to do that but as soon as I insert a delay in the loop it stop working.
I have tried numerous ways to implement the delay such as :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dealDealerCard:faceUp:) withObject:self afterDelay:2.0];
```

which just freezes up all the buttons. I also tried the CCSequence with run action. I also tried the scheduler and NSTimer etc.

here is my code:

```
// if the stand button was pressed

-(void)standButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 BJDrawnCard *holeCard = [dealerHand getFlippedCard];
 [holeCard flipCard];
 while ([dealerHand getTotal]<=17){
    [self performSelector:@selector(dealDealerCard:faceUp:)   withObject:self afterDelay:2.0];

}
```

and here is the method:

```
// Deal Dealers Card

 -(void)dealDealerCard:(id) dummy faceUp:(BOOL)isFaceUp
{
drawnCard=[havila drawFromDeck];
if (isFaceUp) {
[drawnCard setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache  sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:drawnCard.imageFileName]];
}else [drawnCard setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache   sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:@"Backside.png"]];
[dealerHand getCard:drawnCard];
[drawnCard setScale:0.5f];
[drawnCard setPosition:[self shoePosition]];
[cardsheet addChild:drawnCard];
// animate the cards
float cardVelocity = (sqrtf((size.width*size.width)+(size.height*size.height)))/0.5; //     set the base speed for the movment

// calculate the time needed to move the card
CGPoint moveDifference = ccpSub([self dealerCardPosition],
                                [self shoePosition]);
float moveDuration = ccpLength(moveDifference) /
cardVelocity;

// define the movement
CCMoveTo *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:
                  moveDuration position:[self dealerCardPosition]];
CCDelayTime *delay = [CCDelayTime
                      actionWithDuration:0.5];

//Run the action

[drawnCard runAction:[CCSequence actions:move,delay,nil]];

numDealerHits++;

}
```

so to sum it up: I'm trying to run a conditional loop that will call this method with a 2.0 sec delay between calls until total is 17.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: General rule:  Never code a delay in a GUI thread.  You need to break the operation into pieces that can be dispatched with delays in-between.

Comment: re "I am .... " ... the only bad question is the one not asked. I find it cool that you practice the trade/art/science for kicks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys,I tried the answers provided bellow with no luck. I think Hot Licks is probably right and I need to separate the GUI somehow from the main code,maybe it'll work then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)standButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
   BJDrawnCard *holeCard = [dealerHand getFlippedCard];
   [holeCard flipCard];
   if ([dealerHand getTotal]<=17){
      [self performSelector:@selector(dealDealerCard:faceUp:)   withObject:self afterDelay:2.0];

  }
}
```

at the very end of your selector, determine if more and if there are more,

```
 if ([dealerHand getTotal]<=17) {
     id more = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    [self performSelector:@selector(dealDealerCard:faceUp:)   withObject:self afterDelay:2.0];
}];
    [drawnCard runAction:[CCSequence actions:move,delay,more,nil]];
} else {
    [drawnCard runAction:[CCSequence actions:move,delay,nil]];
}
```

Comment: He has tried using performSelector, anyways i won't comment on this. I just want to know how did you get the CCCallBlock class?

Comment: i think it appeared in cocos2d 2.0. This wont block the UI.

Comment: Cool, i didn't know that its from the framework. I upvote your answer just for this one reason.

Comment: very handy ... use it for all sorts of things, like playing a sound effect mid-stream in complex sequences.

Comment: Thanks guys, all the provided answers work if called only once. As soon as I try to run them inside a loop the GUI freezes.

Comment: Thanks Yves, that got me closer to the solution.although I had to write another method that is almost similar with a lot of duplicate code but basically what I learned was that I can't run a delay inside a loop. must be a cocos 2D or something. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Using the first solution is freezing UI because your delaying on GUI thread.

You can try with GCD

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

Comment: Its GCD and i have the power to edit your post +1 nevertheless.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio, your code works fine for one execution but I need to run it inside a conditional loop and thats when my buttons freeze.

Comment: You can just try to add the some the delay for each step you make. For example you add start with a int variable initialized to 0 an then for every loop you increment that variable and use it as the delay for the dispatch. So you will have your action executed at distance of 2 seconds each other and the gui doesn't freeze.

Comment: hmm this doesn't work inside a loop, at least not to update uielements - everything is executed at once. Also if I call setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay directly after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this which won't freeze the UI and will launch with a delay

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

      //do work
    });
```

Comment: Thanks waf, your code works good if executed once. My problem is that it needs to run as part of a loop and that's when my buttons freeze and nothing happens.

Comment: hmm this doesn't work inside a loop, at least not to update uielements - everything is executed at once. Also if I call setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay directly after.